# How to set a Core Data attribute in Entity2 via a relationship from Entity1 with Cocoa Bindings

Tags: macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have two entities in my Core Data project: Entity1 and Entity2. I've setup an array controller for Entity1 which displays a table view and a few properties in text fields next to it. It's a simple app for data entry, nothing fancy - all built using Cocoa Bindings. All values are saved and retrieved correctly for attributes on Entity1. Here's how I'm binding the text fields:

```
Value - Bind to Entity1ArrayController
Controller Key: selection
Model Key Path: attribute
```

Both entities have a one-to-one relationship and I would like to be able to bind an attribute from Entity2 to another text field so I can set a value just like it works so well above on Entity1. I assumed I would just bind this to the same array controller and enter the relationship and attribute as key path, like so:

```
Controller Key: selection
Model Key Path: relationship.attribute
```

Even though the code compiles, and I can enter a value, it isn't saved or retrieved. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Bind an NSObjectController to the relationship and then bind the text field to that.

Comment: Thanks Wain, sounds interesting! How do I bind the Object Controller though? Do I bind it to Entity2 in the Attributes pane (where I have a choice of Class or Entity)? And under Bindings, do I bind the Object Controller to the Array Controller as Availability, Controller Content or Parameters?